# Button to load different page in same webView

Tags: xcode, swift, uiwebview

I have a webview loading a local HTML page after pressing a button in a view controller. How would I put a button under the webview to load different content in the same web view?
ViewController has no extra code entered just a button in storyboard with a present modal segue to the webView controller
webView has the following code.

```
//
//  WebViewer.swift
//  TestWebView
//
//  Created by Colin McGarry on 13/03/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Colin McGarry. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class WebViewer: UIViewController {

var page = "2page"

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!


@IBAction func close(sender: AnyObject) {
 println(sender.tag)
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func reLoad(sender: AnyObject) {
 println(sender.tag)
page = "1page"
 webView!.reload()
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

  if let htmlFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(page, ofType: "html"){
    let htmlData = NSData(contentsOfFile: htmlFile)
    let baseURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath)
    webView.loadData(htmlData, MIMEType: "text/html", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: baseURL)
  }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Under the webView i've placed two buttons, one to close and go back to the viewcontroller, the other I wanted to reload a different webpage in this view. 
I tried an if statement with the sender.tag of the reload button but it wasn't recognised. Neither was the segue identifier from the first viewController

Comment: I removed [tags from the title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), corrected an over-broad tag, and clarified the question a bit. You should include your current code, however.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from an unanswered question.

i changed my reload() function to.

```
@IBAction func reLoad(sender: AnyObject) {
println(sender.tag)
page = "1page"

if let htmlFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(page, ofType: "html"){
let htmlData = NSData(contentsOfFile: htmlFile)
let baseURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath)
webView.loadData(htmlData, MIMEType: "text/html", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: baseURL)
}

}
```

I'm thinking that it would probably be better to put the repeated code in a function and call it each time.